# How to read just the ticker name in input.symbol in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My script is allowing the user to input different tickers. Currently, I have my script just reading the input and outputting it onto a table. The table displays "NYSE:AAPL", when I would like it to just output "AAPL".
I read the input in like this: `s01 = input.symbol("AAPL", "Symbol")`

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I know I can use syminfo.ticker to get the current ticker name without exchange; but I don't know how to use this on my input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your string is NYSE:AAPL. You want to use `:` as a delimeter and split this string. Then you want to get the second one in the list (index 1).

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
s01 = input.symbol("AAPL", "Symbol")

getName(_str) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _chars = str.split(array.get(_pair, 1), "")  // Index 1
    string _return = array.join(_chars, "")

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 2, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = str.tostring(s01))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 1, text = getName(s01))
```

[image]

Comment: Yup this is it. With my python experience I should have thought about this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.